# How to update a Widget in OREO (AlarmManager stops after some hours/days)

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, alarmmanager, android-8.0-oreo

I have a information widget which I'm updating each 60 seconds. Before OREO I did it using a service, but now, you can't do it because you can't use the service when the app is in the background, so I followed some posts here and used a alarm and AlarmManager to update the widget.

The problem  is that it works for some hours, but in one or two days, the onReceive method of the alarm is not being called anymore. something happens because the alarm stops without user removing the widget, so the wiget stops getting updated.

It seems that AlarmManager is not the best way to do this or I'm doing something wrong.

This is my widget alarm receiver:

```
public class WidgetAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final static String TAG = "WidgetAlarmReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onReceive");

        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, AppWidget.class);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = WidgetHelper.getInstance().generateRemoteViews(context);

        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(componentName, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

This is the source code of the widget where I start the alarm:

```
public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = WidgetHelper.getInstance().generateRemoteViews(context);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

private void startWidgetAlarm(Context context){
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetAlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000, alarmIntent);
}

private void stopWidgetAlarm(Context context){
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.cancel(sender);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    startWidgetAlarm(context);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);
    stopWidgetAlarm(context);
}
}
```

Portion of my manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".AppWidget">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/new_app_widget_info" />
</receiver>

<receiver android:name=".WidgetAlarmReceiver"  android:exported="false"/>
```

Comment: One of the bad things about AlarmManager is that you have to re-register after a device reboot, maybe that's what you're experiencing. You can try to use JobScheduler ==> https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129

Comment: @HedShafran can't use it because I need to execute this in lower devices not compatibles with JobScheduler. Also, the device didn't get rebooted, so it's not the cause for the alarm to stop.

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: @earthw0rmjim Nexus 5X updated to 8.1

Comment: @NullPointerException Did you find a solution? I have the same pb. Android O is a pain in the neck. Dev did not really care about backward compatibility.

Comment: I'm using Android O (Nexus) but I can hardly reproduce the problem. However, some of my client does complain this mythology (AlarmManager) no longer work. My plan is to migrate to WorkManager. However, I can hardly test it, since I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience it's best to use a one time alarm and re-register it once triggered, because for repeating alarms Android might think you're abusing the AlarmManager.. So this is the method I'm using:

```
void registerOneTimeAlarm(PendingIntent alarmIntent, long delayMillis, boolean triggerNow) {
    int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    long timeInMillis = (System.currentTimeMillis() + (triggerNow ? 0 : delayMillis));

    if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, alarmIntent);
    } else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, alarmIntent);
    } else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

Maybe it will work for you as well.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to update a widget when the device is asleep.

Comment: So use `setExact()', you can alter the code as you want.. But the approach is what matters...

Comment: Aren't there better ways to achieve this? It's frustrating

Comment: Not if you want to use the AlarmManager.. It's made for alarms, not for executing a task every 60 seconds.. The approach that I offered should be a good enough solution, That's what I do in my app to achieve a cross versions repeating task with not to much code.

Comment: which other ways do I have different to alarmmanager and available for API 14?